# JavaFX tableview bag on java when i parse and input data from sql

Tags: java, sql, javafx-8

**The Tableview does not completely output data from the sql table, although there are no errors. That is, the problem is that the program outputs only part of the data, although there are some in the sheet itself**

SQL query class (sqlworker)

```
public List<String> gettableManagmet() throws SQLException {
    resSet = statmt.executeQuery("PRAGMA TABLE_INFO('Users');");
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();

    while (resSet.next()) {
        ls.add(resSet.getString("name"));
    }
    System.out.println(ls);
    return ls;
}

    public ObservableList<Users> getdatausermanagment() throws SQLException {
    ObservableList<Users> res = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        resSet = statmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users");
        while (resSet.next()) {
                String id = String.valueOf(resSet.getInt("id"));
                String Login = resSet.getString("Login");
                String Pass = resSet.getString("Pass");
                String Otel = resSet.getString("Otel");
                String isManager = String.valueOf(resSet.getInt("isManager"));
                String isAdmin  = String.valueOf(resSet.getInt("isAdmin"));
                String isBlocked = String.valueOf(resSet.getInt("isBlocked"));
                String CauseBlocking = resSet.getString("CauseBlocking");
                System.out.println(id+ Login+Pass+Otel+isManager+isAdmin+isAdmin+CauseBlocking);
            res.add(new Users(id,Login,Pass,Otel,isManager,isAdmin,isBlocked,CauseBlocking));
        }

        for(Users s : res){
                System.out.println(s);
        }
        return res;
}


public void adddata(TableView table) throws SQLException {
    ObservableList<Users> res = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    resSet = statmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users");
    while (resSet.next()) {
        String id = String.valueOf(resSet.getInt("id"));
        String Login = resSet.getString("Login");
        String Pass = resSet.getString("Pass");
        String Otel = resSet.getString("Otel");
        String isManager = String.valueOf(resSet.getInt("isManager"));
        String isAdmin  = String.valueOf(resSet.getInt("isAdmin"));
        String isBlocked = String.valueOf(resSet.getInt("isBlocked"));
        String CauseBlocking = resSet.getString("CauseBlocking");
        System.out.println(id+ Login+Pass+Otel+isManager+isAdmin+isAdmin+isBlocked+CauseBlocking);
       table.getItems().add(new Users(id,Login,Pass,Otel,isManager,isAdmin,isBlocked,CauseBlocking));
    }
}
```

Users class

```
private final String id;
private final String login;
private final String pass;
private final String otel;
private SimpleStringProperty isManager;
private final String isAdmin;
private final String isBlocked;
private final String causeBloocking;

public Users(String id, String login, String pass, String otel, String isManager, String isAdmin, String isBlocked, String causeBlocking) {
this.id = id;
this.login = login;
this.pass = pass;
this.otel = otel;
this.isManager = new SimpleStringProperty(isManager);
this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
this.isBlocked  = isBlocked;
this.causeBloocking = causeBlocking;

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public String getOtel() {
    return otel;
}

public String getisManager() {
    return isManager.get();
}

public String getisAdmin() {
    return isAdmin;
}

public String getisBlocked() {
    return isBlocked;
}

public String getCauseBloocking() {
    return causeBloocking;
}
```

Class where i  parse data

```
public TableView table;
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    SQLWorker sqlWorker = new SQLWorker();
    table.setEditable(true);
    try {
        for (String s: sqlWorker.gettableManagmet()) {
            TableColumn<Users, String> tb = new TableColumn<>(s);
            tb.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(s));
            tb.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
            tb.setVisible(true);
                            table.getColumns().addAll(tb);
            System.out.println(tb.getProperties());
        }

        System.out.println(table.getColumns().size());

      sqlWorker.adddata(table);



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

fxml file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmzGk.png)

when programme in work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bycgR.png)

sql database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCq2C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues here are

1. you do not adhere to the Java naming conventions for 3 of your getters; `PropertyValueFactory` relies on those: the property passed to the constructor is modified by converting the first letter to upper case and then `PropertyValueFactory` checks for methods with that modified name prefixed with `get` or `is`. It e.g. looks for `getIsManager()` or `isIsManager()` not for `getisManager()`. (Note that this is much easier to read btw.)
2. There's a typo in one of your getter (and the corresponding field) names: It should be `getCauseBlocking()`, not `getCauseBloocking()`